# Certain invoices missing from the "All Invoices" API response

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

We use the Intuit API V2 to import Invoices from QuickBooks Desktop.

At one point we imported a few invoices that no longer show up in the list of "all invoices".
But if we request the invoices "by id" (one at a time) we do get them. They still have an open balance > 0.
Is there a reason why these invoices don't show up in the "all invoices" list? We did request all the pages.

Something that we noticed is that the problematic invoices all have Lines with SalesTaxCodeId 2 and seem to be "Tax returns".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Florin,
I have answered this question many times on Stackoverflow. You need to review the Sync Activity and Sync Status for any error the object may have encountered while syncing from Intuit to the customer's desktop QuickBooks file.

Objects that encounter an error are flagged and no longer appear in a query unless you set a filter to retrieve errored objects.

Lastly, you should always post your xml requests one for the query all and one for the individual.

For your reference:
http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0600_Object_Reference/SyncActivity

http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0600_Object_Reference/SyncStatus

http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0100_Calling_Data_Services/0015_Retrieving_Objects#Objects_in_Error_State